# JQuery Validation Plugin displaying "Please enter a value greater than or equal to 0."

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am going crazy with this issue and I cannot seem to resolve it. I am using this plugin to validate a form on my site: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

This is my `form`:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="regForm">
        <table>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <? for($i = 1; $i <= $qty; $i++):?>
            <tr><td>Guest <?= $i?></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="name"  name="name<?= $i ?>" required/></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="email" name="email<?= $i?>"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="phone" name="phone<?= $i ?>"/></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="course_id" value="<?= the_ID() ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="course_title" value="<?= $course ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="formSend2" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="course_date" value="<?= $date ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="course_location" value="<?= $location ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="course_applicant" value="<?= $user_ID ?>"/>
            </tr>
            <? endfor; ?>
        </table>
        Will you be attending? (Tick for Yes) <input name="attend_box" type="checkbox" value="yes"/><br/> 
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm Registration"/>
        </form>
```

This is my `script`

```
$("#regForm").validate();
$.validator.addMethod("cRequired", $.validator.methods.required,"Customer name required");
$.validator.addMethod("cMinlength", $.validator.methods.minlength,
$.validator.format("Customer name must have at least {0} characters"));
$.validator.addClassRules("name", { cRequired: true, cMinlength: 2 });
```

Based on the above, If I try to submit my form without filling in the name field "**Customer Name Required**" is displayed. That works.

If I only put in one character then "**Customer name must have at least 2 characters**" is displayed. That works.

However the problem arises when I type 2 or more characters into the field. I get this error message being displayed on the field and I have no idea why.

**Please enter a value greater than or equal to 0.**

I really don't know what is going on here.

Comment: Since the PHP is evaluated on the server _before_ it gets to the JavaScript, please only show us the _rendered_ HTML as shown in the browser source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not showing the problem you described: [jsfiddle.net/xQdZv](http://jsfiddle.net/xQdZv)

Otherwise, update your OP with the actual *rendered* HTML as seen by the JavaScript.

---

There is absolutely no logical reason to create custom methods which are identical to their default counterparts. You can just safely use the original versions....

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#regForm").validate(); // <- initialize plugin

    // create a new compound rule called "name"
    // assign compound rule using 'class="name"'
    $.validator.addClassRules("name", {  
        required: true,  // <- standard rule
        minlength: 2     // <- standard rule
    });

});
```

That's the purpose of the `addClassRules()` method; to create a compound rule out of multiple standard rules, and then assign it to a `class` name, which is then used to declare the new compound rule on your field.

Your custom messages can be defined inline using these `attributes`.

For `required`:

```
data-msg-required="Customer name required"
```

and for `minlength`:

```
data-msg-minlength="Customer name must have at least {0} characters"
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="name" name="name1" data-msg-required="Customer name required" data-msg-minlength="Customer name must have at least {0} characters" />
```

You also don't need the `required` attribute since you've already defined `required` within your `class` compound rule above.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/86GL5/**